# What are the sharpest known tail bounds for $\chi_k^2$ distributed variables?

Tags: probability, chi-squared-test

Let $X \sim \chi^2_k$ be a chi-squared distributed random variable with $k$ degrees of freedom. What are the sharpest known bounds for the following probabilities

$$
\mathbb{P}[X > t] \leq 1 - \delta_1(t, k)
$$

and

$$
\mathbb{P}[X < z] \leq 1 - \delta_2(z, k)
$$

where $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$ are some functions. Pointers to relevant papers would be appreciated.

Comment: If you define the deltas to be complementary incomplete gamma functions, you obtain exact equalities.  Obviously these are the sharpest possible bounds!  I guess the point of this question is that your calculator doesn't compute incomplete gammas and you're looking for an approximation, but that still omits essential information: how can we answer this question until we know just what your calculator *can* compute?

Comment: I am not interested in computing an upper bound, but obtaining something that I can control analytically. The answer that robin has provided is exactly what I was looking for. The question is, are there more precise bounds than those provided by Massart and Laurent?

Comment: Gamma integrals can be "controlled analytically," so what distinction are you making?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The Sharpest bound I know is that of [Massart and Laurent](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-statistics/volume-28/issue-5/Adaptive-estimation-of-a-quadratic-functional-by-model-selection/10.1214/aos/1015957395.full) Lemma 1 p1325.

A corollary of their bound is:

$$P(X-k\geq 2\sqrt{kx}+2x)\leq \exp (-x) $$

$$P(k-X\geq 2\sqrt{kx})\leq \exp (-x) $$