# Tail inequality on sum of product of normal variables

Tags: normal-distribution, probability-inequalities

For independent random variables $ x_1,..,x_n$  and $y_1,...,y_n$ following normal distribution $N(0,1)$, I need a simple estimate formula for
$P(|\sum_1^n x_iy_i|\ge nt) \leq e^{(?)}$ for $t>1$. Thanks.

Comment: Are the $x_i$ and $y_i$ independent? If so, the inner product is a *subexponential* random variable in the sense of R. Vershynin. See his recent expository introduction to nonasymptotic random matrix theory for relevant bounds of the type you desire.

Comment: Also, do you mean $\geq$ instead of $\leq$ inside the probability function?

Comment: Thanks. You are right, it should be $P(|\sum_1^n x_iy_i| \geq nt)≤e^{(?)}$. Can you be more specific about the reference?

Comment: Yes, all $x_i$ and $y_i$ are independent from each other.

Comment: A very similar question was asked on MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/109989/concentration-results-for-inner-products-of-two-independent-random-gaussian-vecto/ I'm not totally satisfied with any of the answers. I think you can do better. See http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4816/what-are-the-sharpest-known-tail-bounds-for-chi-k2-distributed-variables .

Answer (score 4):

The answer to this question is given in [Berstein's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_inequalities_(probability_theory)),
as presented in Chapter 2 in [Vershynin's book](https://www.math.uci.edu/%7Ervershyn/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.pdf).

For $z_1,...,z_n$ independent, zero-mean, sub-exponential RVs, $$P\left(\left|\sum_i{z_i}\right|\ge nt\right)\le2\exp\left( -cn\cdot\min\left\{ \frac{t^2}{K^2},\frac{t}{K}\right\} \right)$$ where $c$ is a universal constant, $K=\max_i\left\|z_i\right\|_{\psi_1}$ and $\left\|z_i\right\|_{\psi_1}$ is the sub-exponential norm of $z_i$.

Denote $z_i=x_iy_i$. As $x_i,y_i$ are standardized normal RVs, each is a sub-gaussian RV with the sub-gaussian norm $\left\|x_i\right\|_{\psi_2}=\left\|y_i\right\|_{\psi_2}=1$ so $\left\|z_i\right\|_{\psi_1}\le\left\|x_i\right\|_{\psi_2}\cdot\left\|y_i\right\|_{\psi_2}=1$ (see Lemma 2.7.7 in Vershynin's). For convenience, we'll take $\left\|z_i\right\|_{\psi_1}=1$ (lower values would yield tighter bounds). Taking $c=\frac{1}{2}$ (as done in Section 1.3 [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-s997-high-dimensional-statistics-spring-2015/lecture-notes/MIT18_S997S15_CourseNotes.pdf)), we eventually get:

$$P\left(\left|\sum_i{z_i}\right|\ge nt\right)\le2\exp\left( -\frac{n}{2}\cdot\min\left\{ t^2,t\right\} \right)$$