# Tail bounds for F-distribution (not using $\chi^2$ bounds)

Tags: probability, bounds, chi-squared-distribution, f-distribution

Are there any sharp tail bounds for an $F_{p,q}$ distribution? That is, if $X \sim F_{p,q}$, then for a $t_1,t_2 > 0$, what are the sharpest $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$ known such that

$$P(X > t_1) \leq 1 - \delta_1(t_1, p,q)\,,  $$
$$P(X < t_2) \leq 1 - \delta_2(t_2, p,q)\,.  $$

In principle, once could use sharp tail bounds for $\chi^2_p$ and $\chi^2_q$ using [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4816/what-are-the-sharpest-known-tail-bounds-for-chi-k2-distributed-variables?noredirect=1&lq=1), but are there known bounds that are obtained more directly?

From Ben's comment, a trivial bound exists by taking $\delta_1$ as the cdf evaluated at $t_1$. Of course, this doesn't work for me. I am not looking for a specific functional form, so I don't know how to exclude this trivial bound from being a viable answer.

Comment: As presently posed, the sharpest bounds are just the ones that give the exact area under the distribution -i.e., you can take $\delta_1 = \int_0^{t_1} F_{p,q}(t) dt$ where $F_{p,q}$ is the density of the F-distribution.  Unless you impose some restriction on the allowable functional forms, this is a trivial problem.